# Assign privilege level (Organization) greater then read privilage level (Local) - MS Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am working on MS Dynamics CRM 2011, There are two different business units A and 
B. users in Business unit A have assign privilege of Organization level on incident while read privilege only to Business unit level.Now when a user from business unit A assigns an incident to User in business unit B. it throws exception that user in business unit A don't have read privilege to incident as it is going to assign to Business unit B and he don't have more then business unit level privilege for Read. If i increase the read privilege on user in  business unit A to parent child or organization level, user start viewing unnecessary incidents which I don't want. How can we handle such scenario in CRM 2011.

Is it possible for users to have greater privilege level for assign then read ? As if i assigns incident to greater level of read, CRM does not allow me to assign due to read privileges.

Comment: Assigning an entity to another user should update the owning business unit of the record.  How is it getting "assigned"

Comment: its not getting assigned, while assigning to BU-B user-2, error logs shows that User-1 of BU-A  don't have the read privilege on record.